# Numerical analysis matrix image in python

Tags: python, image, matrix, numerical-analysis

what can i do with a matrix image?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img=mpimg.imread('image.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
```

i've already thought:
-difference between same image to notice some movement
-Transpose matrix to rotate the image 
are there other operation that i can do, closer numerical analysis ?

Comment: Your question is very broad. Can you narrow it down? And please explain what "numerical analysis" has to do with it--the two operations you mention do not use numerical analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty broad, open-ended question, but here are a few thoughts:

- Resize the image using various interpolation schemes (e.g. [bicubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) ).
- There are plenty of things you can do with Fourier analysis.
  [FFTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) allow you to observe spatial frequency content ([SciPy FFT library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html)), and
  [DCTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) are used in JPEG compression ([SciPy dct library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html)).
- Color manipulations. Darken/lighten image, make image more red or yellow, etc.
- Histograms of color content.
- [Edge detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection)
- Combine several images together to make an animation and save as a GIF or AVI.

There are libraries for a lot of this, but I gathered that you were in the mood to reinvent the wheel.